# Troubleshooting dynamically generated KML

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, django-templates, python-2.7

I use [dynamically generated KML](http://www.koolbusiness.com) that fails intermittently seemingly because of "timing issues" with Google's server's. Last time I checked it worked but that seems like a coincident. Should I make a cron job that accesses the page every 5 minutes to make data stay fresh in memory? The serverside KML generator is:

```
class KMLHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public,max-age=%s' \
            % 86400
        start = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=60)
        from google.appengine.api import memcache
        memcache_key = 'ads'
        data = memcache.get(memcache_key)
        if data is None:
            a = Ad.all().filter('modified >',
                                start).filter('published =',
                    True).order('-modified').fetch(1000)
            memcache.set('ads', a)
        else:
            a = data
        dispatch = 'templates/kml.html'
        template_values = {'a': a, 'request': self.request,
                           'host': os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST',
                           os.environ['SERVER_NAME'])}
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dispatch)
        output = template.render(path, template_values)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = \
            'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'
        self.response.headers['Content-Length'] = len(output)
        self.response.out.write(output)
```

--
The template file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
{% for ad in a %}
{% if ad.geopt %}
<Placemark><name></name><description>
<![CDATA[{% if ad.uri2view %}<img src="{{ ad.uri2view }}">{% endif %}<a href="http://www.koolbusiness.com/vi/{{ad.key.id}}"> {{ ad.title }} </a><br/>{{ad.text|truncatewords:20}}]]></description><Point><coordinates>{{ad.geopt.lon|floatformat:2}},{{ad.geopt.lat|floatformat:2}}</coordinates></Point></Placemark>{% endif %}{% endfor %}</Document></kml>
```

--
I've also run the [output](http://www.koolbusiness.com/list.kml) through a KML validator to ensure that it is correct. It is dynamically generated and I try to cache it. It just fails intermittently for no apperant reason. I have Python that generates the KML and the code is checked and should be working. I don't see where the program is wrong? I can take the output of my script, save it as a static kml file, and that works and the KML is valid so it seems there are "timing issues" in serving it to google when it is being dynamically generated. But how can I troubleshoot this further? I could change the whole strategy to using JSON instead but that will be a lot of recoding and I think I'm close to making it work.

The 3 strategies I can think of is

- Change to Jinja2 templates
- Change to JSON instead of KML
- Write a cron job that accesses the file every 5 minutes to keep the data in memcache
  [image]
  Thanks for any help

Comment: What kind of failures? Are you seeing errors in your App Engine logs?

Comment: I occassionally see timeout errors in the log and when there is a KML failure I *think* it is a deadlineexceedederror and will check exactly.

Comment: What fails is pretty vital to actually knowing what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's taking too long to build your KML so Google is giving up.  I tested the [link](http://www.koolbusiness.com/list.kml) a few times and each time it took several seconds to load, sometimes >5 seconds.  The servers that download and render these KML files will time out / give up if the file can't be loaded quickly.  This sort of behavior is consistent with intermittent failures when the file can't be loaded sometimes or the cache (when a good load has occured) expires.

If the process that generates the KML can't be improved, you should cache the actual file data you generate so you can return it quicker in the future.  Using the Task Queue API / Cron you could keep that cache up to date by running a rebuild task every N minutes.